# CharacterController move statement throwing errors every time the player collides with an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

I am trying to detect collision with my `CharacterController`, which was working just fine except it was throwing errors every time the player collided with an object.
This is the error:

> OnControllerColliderHit couldn't be called because the expected
> parameter Collision doesn't match ControllerColliderHit.

But, when I added another `if`-statement, it doesn't work at all and throws the same error. (The if-statements do not trigger) The error is triggering inside of my movement script instead of my collision script at line 47. Here is the movement script:

```
private CharacterController controller;
private float gravity;
Vector3 physics;
public Transform groundloc;
bool isgrounded;
public float grounddistance = 0.4f;
public LayerMask groundmask;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
isgrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundloc.position, grounddistance, groundmask);
float axis = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
if (isgrounded && physics.y < 0)
{
physics.y = -2f;
}

gravity -= 9.81f * Time.deltaTime;
float zaxis = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
Vector3 movement = transform.right * axis + transform.forward * zaxis;
controller = gameObject.GetComponent<CharacterController>();
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
{
physics.y = Mathf.Sqrt(6.00f * -2f * gravity);
}
controller.Move(movement * 5f * Time.deltaTime);
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
{
controller.Move(movement * 5.00005f * Time.deltaTime);
}
physics.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
controller.Move(physics * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

(Code truncated for readability)

Comment: Your code doesn't have more than 40 lines, and where is the error? Also what is line 47? Do you want the viewers to count the lines from beginning of the code? Care to mention the line of code where you get the error?

Answer (score 0):

`OnControllerCollidrerHit()` takes in the argument of type `ControllerColliderHit` and not of the type `Collision`.

```cs
void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
{
    // do something
}
```

Refer to the docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnControllerColliderHit.html

Comment: The code error is occurring inside of my movement script which I have added in my question.